# DataGrid / GridView corrupted columns when saving to Xps

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, xps

I have a table that I need to save as an xps (or pdf) file. To do that, I have a custom control that has a header and the table itself, here's what it looks like in the UI:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfGlJ.png (Sorry, I am not allowed to post images yet :) )
 So I just create an instance of this control, pass it a datacontext, measure, rearrange it and write it to an XpsDocument as a visual and it is supposed to be as simple as that. However, in the result xps file it looks different, the columns don't get their width right:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgpcz.png
I also tried a ListView with a GridView - same story, the columns shrink.
Here's how I write the xps file:

```
            var xpsFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Details.xps");
        using (var pack = Package.Open(xpsFileName))
        {
            using (var doc = new XpsDocument(pack))
            {
                var dataContext = SeiteDataContextBekommen(0);
                var visual = BerichtViewErstellen();
                visual.DataContext = dataContext;
                visual.Measure(PageSize);
                visual.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, PageSize.Width, PageSize.Height));
                visual.UpdateLayout();
                var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
                writer.Write(visual);
            }
        }
```

Here's the Xaml of the DataGrid, although there's not much to see there:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding MitarbeiterBestellungen}" 
              CellStyle="{StaticResource ZelleStyle}"
              AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              Background="Transparent" 
              FontSize="12"
              GridLinesVisibility="None">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Angebeort" Binding="{Binding Standort}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ZentriertZelleStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding MitarbeiterID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mitarbeiter" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Mitarbeitername}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Menge" Binding="{Binding Menge}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ZentriertZelleStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bezeichnung" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Bezeichnung}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Preis" Binding="{Binding Preis, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="OK" Width="64" CellStyle="{StaticResource OkZelleStyle}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I also tried creating a paginator and wrap my UserControl with a DocumentPage, I tried using VisualsCollator for the Xps writer, but the result is always the same. It looks like I am missing something very simple here, I will be grateful if you could help me find what it is.

BTW, I have to save the control WITHOUT showing it, as it supposed to be done by a windows service later.

P.S. The problem is that I use the * width in some columns. I replaced them with fixed sizes and it now displays correctly. Is there a way to make it work with *s?

Comment: I've got the same problem. Has anyone come up with a solution for this?